# Link between the Land of Israel giving fruit when Jews living there and biblical Shmita?

Tags: eretz-yisrael, fruits, shmita

***Shemita*** (the prohibition to work the land every seventh year) is today observed in Israel as a rabbinic commandment. It **will become again observed biblically when the majority of Jews will live in Israel** (see Rambam [MT Shemita 10:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1007174/jewish/Shemita-Chapter-10.htm) and ff).

R Chaim Drukman (in his book [Kim'a kim'a - Step by Step](https://machon.oretzion.com/document/step%20by%20step%20example.pdf)) brings multiple sources showing that, after the exile, **the land of Israel starts to give fruit when the Jews start to return**. (e.g., [Sanhedrin 98a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.98a.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.98a.3?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sanhedrin.98a.3.1&lang2=bi) there, [Megila 17b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.17b.16?lang=en&with=all&lang2=en), [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.17b.16?lang=en&p2=Rashi_on_Megillah.17b.16.1&lang2=en) there).

**I am interested in the linkage between the land of Israel giving its fruit when the Jews return and the *shemita* becoming again biblically observed once the majority of Jews will live in Israel**

Could there be a strong link between the two ideas? Have others written on the topic?